# why laravel application is not starting properly?

Tags: php, linux, laravel, frameworks, laravel-artisan

I followed the instructions to install composer on my live linux VPS and then installed laravel using the documentation from the official site.

**composer installation:**

```
 php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" > composer-setup.php
 php -r "if (hash('SHA384', file_get_contents('composer-setup.php')) === 'fd26ce67e3b237fffd5e5544b45b0d92c41a4afe3e3f778e942e43ce6be197b9cdc7c251dcde6e2a52297ea269370680') { echo 'Installer verified'; } else { echo 'Installer corrupt'; unlink('composer-setup.php'); }"
 php composer-setup.php
 php -r "unlink('composer-setup.php');"
```

**laravel installation:**

```
composer global require "laravel/installer=~1.1"
```

created a new project inside a directory inside my domain main directory (public_html)

```
laravel new newapp
```

so a directory named newapp was created with all the application files.
and from the newapp directory I ran this command.

```
php artisan serve
```

I get a message says "laravel development server started on http://localhost.com:8000

all successful, but, I'm not sure where to head so I can go to the new site.
I mean what is the url that users should write in the browser so they reach the new app or site?

Comment: It should be localhost:8000. You haven't created anything, yet, though so all you will see is the default page.

Comment: i'm not working on localhost, im working on a live domain. and I tried www.domainname.com:8000 but nothing happens

Comment: Okay. Then you need to setup your virtual hosts (assuming Apache2) to point to the public directory of the laravel app. Running 'php artisan serve' is for the development server.

Comment: and what If I want to make multible apps?

Comment: The easiest way to do that would be multiple subdomains i.e. app, app2, app3.

Comment: I just tried this, created a subdomain points to the public directory inside my app, but when trying to open it I get: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: What is in your error log for apache2? I am guessing that this is a permission problem. Try this: chown -R www-data:www-data storage bootstrap/cache

Comment: Laravel requires write permissions for the storage and bootstrap/cache directories, so assigning ownership to www-data should suffice (gives the web server write access).

Comment: chown: invalid user: `www-data:www-data'

Comment: Not all versions of Linux use the `www-data` user. Frankly, given the questions you're asking, you either a) need to learn a lot about setting up a VPS to be a webserver (nginx/Apache config etc.) or b) should use something like https://forge.laravel.com/ to set this up for you.

Answer (score 2):

Running php artisan serve is a way to run a Laravel application in development mode. You can also achieve the same thing with the command php -S localhost:8000 -t public.

If you want to deploy the application for production, you should create a virtual host to point to the public directory of the laravel application.